# Listview contents saving to Sqlite database-Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-sqlite

I ve a `ListView` with two `TextView`s.This is my result page.So I need to store the results to sqlite database.I have a save Button.When user click on that save button there should be a popup appears that contains new-user and list of existing users.When I select new user the data will save to a new table with table name as new user name.When I click an existing user the data will add to the existing table.Ho can I achieve this.? How to create a table dynamically..??

Comment: post your main code...

Comment: I havnt tried yet..I donno how to start.

Comment: You sure you want to create a new table for every user?

Comment: then first try yourself. nobody helps you directly..

Comment: @swayam Yea.Because i want to insert new data.when an existing user do the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your query -

When your pop-up appears:
On the click of new user button - Create a form for submitting new user details.
and

On the click of existing users button - use user contacts API to add users from the contacts.

I would suggest you to save the user entries to a single table.

Comment: how can we store the data of all users in single table.? for one time is good. but when an existing user runs a second test where should we store the results?